# How to save list in column in .csv file instead of rows?

Tags: python, csv

I want to save a list in .csv. I had syntax, but it save in rows instead of columns. Please give suggestion. Thanks in advance.
My syntax is:

```
import csv
n=0
x=[]
while n < 10:
    n = n+1
    x.append(n)
with open('test.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows([x])
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you martineau. It improved  but it has []. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The way `writerows` functions is that it takes an iterable (in this case, a list) and prints each item on that iterable on its own line, separated by delimiter (by default, a `,`)

What happens here is that you're passing `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]` which means there is a single row (`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`) to be written out.

If you want to write each item to it's own row, you need to provide each item as its own list:

```py
import csv
n = 0
x = []
while n < 10:
    n = n+1
    x.append([n])

print(x)
with open('test.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(x)
```

Here, I've taken out the `[]` around `x` in the last line and moved them into `x.append([n])` to create `x` that is `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the writerows line by:

```
writer.writerows(np.array([x]).T)
```

It should work. (you should `import numpy as np`, of course)

Comment: Thanks Igor Rivin. Yep it works. Is it possible without calling np?

Comment: @rrcmks Yes, see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-transpose-elements-of-two-dimensional-list/

Comment: Thank you  Igor Rivin. It prints exactly as I required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the [`csv.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method an "an iterable of row objects", which can be a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). Also note you should open csv files with `newline=''` in Python 3.x as shown in the [module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Here's how to do it. Note how each value in the list is (temporarily) turned into a list of one item by the `[v]` part of the expression.

```
import csv

x = list(range(10))

with open('testfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(([v] for v in x))

print('done')
```